# Add Z/OS license to an installed ODBC Cli driver on Cloud

Tags: php, db2, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I deployed a PHP Cloud Foundry app using PHP buildpack. This buildpack has ODBC Cli extention so I can use DB2 functions and I can connect to DB2 on cloud. But I can't connect to a Z/OS DB2 database via Secure Gateway bevause I receive license error. I have to license the driver files somehow on Cloud. I have the license file. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cloud hostname is configured with "IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI" then you can connect to Db2 for Z/OS if you add a Db2-connect license file to the license subdirectory of the installation-directory for "IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI" - before starting your application.

The name of the license file will be similar to "db2consv_ee.lic" or "db2consv_as.lic" or "db2consv_zs.lic".

More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0024162.html).

Comment: It took me a while until I found the location on Bluemix server: By default if you use PHP buildpack with DB2 extension, this is the destination: /home/vcap/app/ibmdb_clidriver/license/db2consv_zs.lic'